# Role-specific login: override getUnauthorizedURL() in shiro / tapestry-security

Tags: java, security, tapestry, shiro

How would one redirect a user to a specific login page depending on the role with **shiro / tapestry-security**?

I've tried to override the `getUnauthorizedURL` method in order to achieve that, some things along the lines of this, but obviously, there seems more to it than I understand:

```
@RequiresRoles("foo")
public class foobar {

  public String getUnauthorizedURL() {
    return "foobar_login_url";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user needs to login it means the user is still unauthenticated and thus there is no user-specific role yet. To the best of my understanding there is no practical way to have role-specific login pages.

Comment: The user goes to `/foo` and if not authenticated, should be redirected to `/foobar_login_url`. On any other route, the unauthenticated router goes to `/login` (as setup in `configuration.add(SecuritySymbols.LOGIN_URL, "/login");`). What I would want here is to override the `getLoginURL()` method.